# MySQL group by and where

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a sql table: table1 with records look like this:

```
id1    id2     status    value
A     A123     VN        1
A     A234     AB        2
B     B123     VN        3
B     B321     AB        4
C     C324     AB        5
```

I want to get the id1, id2 whose status is VN and the value to be the max for those records who share the same id1.

In this case, the output should look like

```
id1    id2     status    value
A     A123     VN        2
B     B123     VN        4
```

I am not quite sure how to write the query and any help would be appreciated!

Here is what I have done so far.

```
select
    test1.*
from test1 
inner join
(select 
    part_id 
from table1
where status = 'VN') a
on test1.id1 = a.id1;
```

And I could get this but I don't know how to correctly do the group and max(value):

```
id1    id2     status    value
A     A123     VN        1
A     A234     AB        2
B     B123     VN        3
B     B321     AB        4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way is to use a correlated subquery for just getting the the max value;

```
SELECT id1, id2, status, 
  (SELECT MAX(value) FROM test1 t2 WHERE t1.id1 = t2.id1) value 
FROM test1 t1
WHERE status = 'VN'
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71c84/2).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the moment you were answering this question, I have written a query more than 20 lines with joins... this is extremely help!

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear but I think this will help you.

```
SELECT T1.id1, T1.id2, T1.status, T2.value
FROM tbl T1
JOIN
(SELECT id1, MAX(value) value FROM tbl GROUP BY id1) T2
ON T1.id1 = T2.id1
WHERE status = 'VN'
```